# Regex not working as expected in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex that works in RegexBuddy but doesn't work in Java.

This is my regex: `(?<=(files)\\s)(.*)`

This is the string I'm testing it on: `"–files /root1/file1.dat;/root/file2.txt"`

In RegexBuddy it's returning: `"/root1/file1.dat;/root/file2.txt"` but in Java it returns just the literal word `files`.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: When you say "it's returning..." what exactly do you mean?  Your original regex should have `matcher.group()` and `matcher.group(2)` containing `/root1/.....` but `matcher.group(1)` will contain the string `files` because of the capturing parentheses within the look-behind.

Comment: @IanRoberts I made mistake by using group(1). After I got explanation I've fixed the code and now is as it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this regex:

```
(?<=files\\s)(.*)
```

**EDIT** add explanation

I guess you were taking `group(1)`

your regex: `(?<=(files)\\s)(.*)` has three match groups:

```
group 0:/root1/file1.dat;/root/file2.txt
group 1:files
group 2:/root1/file1.dat;/root/file2.txt
```

mine: `(?<=files\\s)(.*)` has two:

```
group 0:/root1/file1.dat;/root/file2.txt
group 1:/root1/file1.dat;/root/file2.txt
```

the group in look-behind is actually not necessary, and your `(.*)` became `group(2)` if you want to get `/root1.....$', you don't have to group,

```
(?<=files\\s).*
```

will do the job.

anyway, if you want to stick to your regex, take `group(2)`

I hope it is clear explained.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any rule about  bracket in this case that would be good to know?

Comment: This really helps me a lot. And you are right, I didn't know and used group1.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I'm running this and i see no difference if i put the brackets around files or not. The brackets inside the look-behind don't make a difference.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class regex
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String s = "-files /root1/file1.dat;/root/file2.txt";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=-(files)\\s)(.*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        System.out.println(m.find());
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Note that if you are trying to parse command line parameters like this then it is probably a bad idea as you will run into problems (potentially) with this overlapping on other parameters. What about the case such as " -docs freds-files -files blah.txt" ?

Comment: The problem was that I used group(1). I know regex isn't perfect but I'm doing project where that don't matter. I just have to put code into that regex for stop returning after last space